# Front end forms for contacts?

Tags: wordpress, integration

With Caldera forms now no longer an option, what are some best practices for new users to enter contact details into CiviCRM ?  Also, what is the best way to show user info on the front end of a website?

Answer (score 4):

You have several options.

The oldest option is profiles (**Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Profiles**).  These are basic in functionality, but are still my first choice for newsletter signups.

Second is FormBuilder (Enable at **Administer > System Settings > Extensions**, then find at **Administer > Customize Data and Screens > FormBuilder**).  This is the successor to profiles and Caldera Forms. It does many things that both are incapable of, but still has rough edges - e.g. there's no easy way to add a submitter to a group automatically. But it improves significantly with each month.

Third is Caldera Forms.  Some CiviCRM developers are maintaining a fork of Caldera Forms that continues to work.  I don't have details but someone else can surely respond. Here is [a blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/andreas/how-you-can-help-making-caldera-forms-php-8-ready) with links to more info.

Fourth is using Form Processor with just about any form building tool.  This is the most complex option, but is much more powerful than any of the others.  It's also possible to use FormBuilder + Form Processor in this way. I'v

Answer (score 0):

Totally agreed with Jon G. We are using a mix of the solution above depending on what needs to be achieved. Form Processor and Contact Form 7 do work well together.
The remaining question is for paid membership which is not yet handled by FormBuilder but might be soon.